# Magento CE Block Permissions

Tags: magento

I have just upgraded from Magento 1.8 to 1.9.2.4 and now I see in my var/log/system

Security problem: core/template has not been whitelisted

However when I move my mouse over System -> configuration ->permissions -> blocks 
I have a row that says   core/template   allowed

So I am not sure where else to look. I cleared the Magento cache as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: You've cleared the cache which is good, but your configuration may still be cached by the web server. You might be falling prey to the APC cache, in which case a restart of Apache/Nginx and/or PHP-FPM might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using some complex sql statement in your block. 
Check this link https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details APPSEC-1063, addressing possible SQL injection. Might help.

Comment: I have the patch SUPEE-6788 so I do not thing it is with any issue of SQL injection. But thanks. Any other suggestions?